# picturebox doubleclick even handler

Tags: picturebox

I generate a picturebox in runtime, then I add this event:

```
picbox.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(picbox_DoubleClick);
```

then this:

```
 private void picbox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
// I do stuff here not related to the question

     }
```

Now, when I double click on the image, it never enters the picbox_DoubleClick function, what am I doing wrong?

this works like a charm:

```
   picbox.Click += new System.EventHandler(clickpicbox);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the PictureBox and add it to the form?

Comment: `Image tmp = (Image)img.RenderImage(0);` <br/>
`var image = new Bitmap(tmp);`<br/>
`picbox = new PictureBox();`<br/>
`picbox.Image = image;`<br/>

Answer (score 0):

`this.picbox.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(picbox_DoubleClick);`

In general if it's not working, event was not added to correct object.

Comment: this refers to current instance of the class, as you need to add event to correct object.